# Cannot integrate Jersey 2.16 into Tomcat 8.0.12 using servlet 3 plugability feature

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jersey-2.0, servlet-3.0

In new project I decided to use latest Jersey (2.16) with Tomcat 8, but integration scheme described in documentation causes Tomcat to throw NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.binaryNameToPath(WebappClassLoader.java:2503)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findLoadedClass0(WebappClassLoader.java:2708)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1215)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2381)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2370)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>bla.bla.core.jersey.config.JerseyServerConfig</servlet-name>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>bla.bla.core.jersey.config.JerseyServerConfig</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is the listing of JerseyServerConfig:

```
package ru.huawei.rnd.bulksms.core.jersey.config;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import ru.huawei.rnd.bulksms.core.jersey.constants.FILTERS_AND_INTERCEPTORS;
import ru.huawei.rnd.bulksms.core.jersey.constants.JERSEY_FEATURES;

public class JerseyServerConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyServerConfig() {
        register(JERSEY_FEATURES.FORM_PROVIDER);
        register(JERSEY_FEATURES.MULTIPART);
        register(FILTERS_AND_INTERCEPTORS.USER_GZIP_FILTER);
        register(FILTERS_AND_INTERCEPTORS.GZIP_ENCODER);
        packages("bla.bla.rest");
    }

}
```

So, it looks correct according to scheme described [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#deployment.servlet.3) in "4.7.2.2. Deployment using web.xml descriptor". But when I try to call any JAX-RS resource, bang, Tomcat throws NPE. And it seems it's because of missing servlet-class element in web.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are using the [`jersey-container-servlet-core`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core/2.16) dependency. This will work in situations when we declare the servlet container. But when we want to take advantage of the features where Jersey is automatically loaded, we need the [`jersey-container-servlet`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet/2.16)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This artifact has the [`JerseyServletContainerInitializer`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.16/jersey/index.html?org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/init/JerseyServletContainerInitializer.html), which implements [`SerlvetContainerInitializer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) (for Servlet 3.x deployments).

<sub>Tested and got same results as you when using the former artifact, and works fine using the latter.</sub>

Comment: Nah, I completely forgot about container-servlet dependency at all. Shame on me :( But anyway, I added new dependency to my web.xml and stil experiencing same problem :(

Comment: I can start a simple app simply using this as the _only_ dependency (which pull everything else in), and your web.xml config. Try this and see what's wrong with what you have. Maybe clean an build, and check the container to see if it is not using an old app and check the libs

Comment: And did you just say you added the dependency to your **web.xml**???? I hope that was a mistake and you meant to say **pom.xml** :-)

Comment: Sorry, wait. I just forgot to update my artifact configuration, should have also added new dependencies to output :) And yes, surely I added them to pom :D